# Stylesheets and images are not served, but other static files are

Tags: python, django, nginx, gunicorn

I recently used the django `runserver` command to start my server when I was developing it, and I got it to serve the static files fine and well when I was doing this. I decided that I wanted to use Gunicorn and Nginx instead of the `runserver` command. So, I edited my `/etc/nginx/sites-available/mysite` file to look like this:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name xxx.xxx.xxx.133;

    access_log off;

    location /static/ {
        alias /opt/myenv/pysauce/static;
    }

    location / {
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            add_header P3P 'CP="ALL DSP COR PSAa PSDa OUR NOR ONL UNI COM NAV"';
    }
}
```

I also changed the `STATIC_URL` in `mysite/settings.py` to the same is the `location /static/` in my Nginx `sites-available` file. I then started gunicorn with `gunicorn mysite.wsgi:application`, and I was able to go on the site. I know that Gunicorn can't serve static files, but I know Nginx can.

When I went on my website, the really weird part was that my stylesheet weren't served, but the custom fonts, that are also in the static directory with the style sheet was. I was able to confirm this by entering in my address bar `/static/css/foundation.css`, and it resulted in a 404 error. However, when I entered the address, `/static/fonts/UbuntuMono-B.ttf` it prompted a download. Why aren't the stylesheets serving, but other static files are?

Comment: On what port did you run the gunicorn and on which port have you tried to open the project on browser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing that I encourage you to do is to keep a log file. Put the following lines in your config file:

```
access_log /dir/to/your/access.log
error_log /dir/to/your/error.log
```

Next, open your log to see why nginx cannot access those file. If you see

```
[Errno 13] Permission denied
```

Then, it is a permission problem, use the following command to grant access right:

```
chmod -R a+x static
```

Comment: For some reason, I never got a permission denied error as you suggested, but, I did however, set the log files in my home directory. Once I did that, all my static files were served. Also, my error.log file is completely empty.

Comment: @DorianDore so everything is working after adding log files? that's weird, but glad to help :)

Comment: Actually, it turns out my problem was the location /static/ directive. I set it to `alias /opt/myenv/pysauce/static` when the proper setting would be `root /opt/myenv/pysauce`.

Answer (score 1):

use your browser access /static/css/  Can it work?
If can not to access check your server folder permission.

Answer (score 1):

There should be problem with static file permissions. try these two commands

```
sudo chmod -R 777 /opt/myenv/pysauce/static

sudo chown -R 777 /opt/myenv/pysauce/static
```

This way you will give permission to the users to access your static files through their browsers.